# visual studio debugging unit tests en masse

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging

My debug settings break on any exception, which is normally useful when debugging a focused test case.

Sadly, I have let one of the more subtle buggers in, the kind that only shows when some as yet unknown interaction of *all* my tests running. I have a beak point set in the right spot but I can't do it with the debugger breaking on every failing test!

What is the option I need to temporarily only break when it hits a break point?

Cheers,
Berryl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose menu 
    Debug --> Exceptions...

and then just unclick all "User-unhandled" exceptions to only have the debugger break on your break points.

The option I find useful as a general approach to letting the debugger work for you when you aren't looking for a needle in a haystack is to click on User-unhandled exceptions for Common CLR Exceptions.

Cheers,
Berryl